# How to load object array when allow_pickle=False

Tags: python

I am trying to train a model that have images we are trying to classify. whenever I run the code it shows
whole error is as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
 File "c:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\New folder\trainmodel.py", line 14, in <module>
    res = np.load(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action, str(sequence), "{}.npy".format(frame_num)))
  File "C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 432, in load
    return format.read_array(fid, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
  File "C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 787, in read_array
    raise ValueError("Object arrays cannot be loaded when "
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False
```

also the code is given here :

```
from function import *
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
label_map = {label:num for num, label in enumerate(actions)}
# print(label_map)
sequences, labels = [], []
for action in actions:
    for sequence in range(no_sequences):
        window = []
        for frame_num in range(sequence_length):
            res = np.load(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action, str(sequence), "{}.npy".format(frame_num)))
            window.append(res)
        sequences.append(window)
        labels.append(label_map[action])

X = np.array(sequences)
y = to_categorical(labels).astype(int)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.05)

log_dir = os.path.join('Logs')
tb_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=(30,63)))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(actions.shape[0], activation='softmax'))
res = [.7, 0.2, 0.1]

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, callbacks=[tb_callback])
model.summary()

model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
model.save('model.h5')
```

I've tried running numpy on 1.16 version but i am unable to do so. Is there any way I can do this without reverting back to the older version.